Using tipa in beamer: How to match fonts?
I've got a simple problem: I'm accustomed to using TIPA and right now, I'd like to use it in a beamer document. However, since the beamer document class overwrites the standard Latex font and replaces it with some sans serif font, anything I type with TIPA ends up in a completely different font than the rest of the document. It looks terrible.
Can someone please tell me how to

either change TIPA's font so it matches the default beamer font
or change the font in the beamer document so it matches the default TIPA font?

Either of the two would be great. Standard stuff à la \setmainfont doesn't work. I'm using Overleaf, Xelatex.

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

Please note that xelatex isn't the best choice for beamer. It can cause text on note pages to disappear and incorrect overlays. If you need an unicode-aware engine, try lualatex instead.

You could use the serif font theme to get the normal serif latex font:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tipa}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  abc \textipa{[""Ekspl@"neIS@n]}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


If you use pdflatex, you could use sans serif tipa symbols like this:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{tipa}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  abc \textipa{[""Ekspl@"neIS@n]}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


